# Hidden Field Pick up by Google

Tags: html, web, hidden

```
<div id="hiddenDiv" style="display:none;">
Lorem Ipsum. Soumya
</div>
```

I have a HTML code like above. Is it possible google pick up my text while this Div is being hidden. If not then can anyone suggest me how to make any text hidden and google pick up that line from a site.

Comment: Likely not. Google tends not to evaluate hidden/spam text in its search heuristics.

Comment: As long as even Yandex can do it, google should know even if u hide the textblock with javascript on page load/DOM ready events.

Comment: **Read the Google FAQ**. http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66353

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hiding text or links in your content to manipulate Google’s search rankings can be seen as deceptive and is a violation of Google’s Webmaster Guidelines. Text (such as excessive keywords) can be hidden in several ways, including:
Using white text on a white background Locating text behind an image Using CSS to position text off-screen Setting the font size to 0 Hiding a link by only linking one small character—for example, a hyphen in the middle of a paragraph

Taken from http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66353

Meta Tag is not useful if your text length is more than 255

Comment: Thanks Jhilom for providing me this. Though I didn't like the process but it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Search bots can pickup any content that is available as text from your web pages. If you don't want something indexed by google, render it out in an image or so, but given google's reputation, they might find ways to index the content out of it as well. The best option is block bots from indexing specific pages in whole via your robots.txt

Comment: No I want Google pick my text and can direct to my page from those text they picked

Answer (score 0):

You can use meta tag.

<head>
<meta name="description" content="This is Soumya's site">
<meta name="keywords" content="Lorem Ipsum. Soumya, some search word, etc">
<meta name="owner" content="Soumya">
</head>

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simply use some sort of metatags like

```
<meta name="description" content="Awesome Description Here">
<meta name="keywords" content="Some keywords a common user shall never see, but common searchbot will">
```

I mean, Google searchbot will use it not as a content, but as content metadata.
It's the war never-ending between SEO-cheaters and search-drive development groups. Last ones trying their best to know if the content is usefull or/and will ever be shown to user. So that jQuery-solution is a solution to BING only, i guess. Or any other useless search-drive.

PS: No offence, MS.